# Using a light bulb as test / dummy load

Tags: amplifier, power, test, powering

I have an old sony str-d911 [some pics](https://tmraudio.com/old-products/sony-str-d911-stereo-am-fm-receiver-w-graphic-eq-remote/)

I know the str-d911 is a receiver and not an amp but the specs say 100 watts per channel
I tried using a 40 watt and 100 watt light bulb (as a test/dummy load) connected to the left speaker channel playing 60 Hz but it doesn't seem to be putting enough power out to light it.  What am I missing?

[Here's The Spec sheet](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/242636/Sony-Str-D711.html?page=32#manual)

[image: Front-1]

[image: Back]

Video of using a light bulb as a load below.

Comment: You're missing about 100 volts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Use a 24 V lamp instead.

Back of an envelope calculation. The formula I use is P = U * U / R.

Your amplifier: 100w in 4 Ohms --> cirka 20V output.
Put 20 V into a normal 110V / 100W lamp (around 110 Ohms) gives you about 4 W = not enought to light it. Even worse with a 40W lamp (about 320 Ohms) --> about 1.3 W.

The Peavey in the video gives 650W in 4 Ohms --> about 50V --> 20 W or so = enough to light the lamp. Or they might have it bridge coupled, which would give about 100V across the lamp.